# Which front-end framework for a single-page search app?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, vue.js, web-frameworks

I am trying to build a web app that can search through a document. (Target users are currently using a pdf reader to do this). The document has say a thousand "items", and each item has a title, code, description, price, etc. I want the single-page app to update results with each keypress with the most relevant items. Which front-end framework, if any, would be appropriate? I am new to frameworks, but I am guessing something lightweight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both React and Vue would be able to do this, also with such a simple task you are likely to manage it with just pure vanilla JS.

I'd probably recommend having a go at doing it in React first, as that is often seen as the easiest, this question is very opinion-based though so just have a look through the various docs and go with the framework that seems to make the most sense to you.